# send email in asp.net from localhost

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, localhost

I find [this](http://bradkingsley.com/sending-email-from-asp-net-4-c-sample-code/)
solution for sending mail but it gives me eror.Here my values:

```
Message to: anton_putov@mail.ru

Message from: anton_putov@mail.ru

subject: ....
.........
```

I am using visual studio 2010.Must I set any configuration properties or something else?

Comment: Do you have working SMTP service on your local machine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What type of SMTP you are using ? If you dont have your own SMTP settings then you can Use of Google Mail. Here how you can use that.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
  mail.To.Add("Email ID where email is to be send");
  mail.To.Add("Another Email ID where you wanna send same email");
  mail.From = new MailAddress("YourGmailID@gmail.com");
  mail.Subject = "Email using Gmail";

  string Body = "Hi, this mail is to test sending mail"+ 
                "using Gmail in ASP.NET";
  mail.Body = Body;

  mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
  smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
       ("YourUserName@gmail.com","YourGmailPassword");
//Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Visual studio as I understand doesnt have its own smtp server?

Comment: No it doesnt have any. for that you have to install SMTP server and configure that.